# Lost focus edit text android

Tags: android

I have code lost focus edit text, but if edittext on focus, value in edittext can not edit and keyboard not show, please help me, thanks.

```
etkolom1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {

                if (etkolom1.requestFocus()){
                    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
                if(!hasFocus){
                    String a = etkolom1.getText().toString();
                    boolean boo1 = cekET(etkolom1, "i", "8i");

                    if(etkolom1.requestFocus()){
                        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
                    }

                }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please try to explain correctly. Bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to hide the keyboard

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                              getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 

inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                                 InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: not hide keyboard but show keyboard, i will edit value in edittext

Comment: it automatically shows keyboard if you focus an edittext

Comment: but in my app keyboard not show if edittext lost focus, sorry my english not good